# Navigation Bar with on hover drop down

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter, navigation

I'm having difficulty in creating this navigation bar on top of my site.

I have the following on my html atm. Note that this navigation bar is my 2nd navbar on that page, hence the classes for li and a. (Do I also need to make class/id for the sublist?)

```
<div id="navbar2">
      <ul>
          <li class="list"><a class="link" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/A">A</a></li>
          <li class="list"><a class="link" href="">B</a></li>
          <li class="list"><a class="link" href="">C</a></li>
          <li class="list"><a class="link" href="">D</a></li>
          <li class="list"><a class="link" href="">Browse</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="">By Category</a>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="">k</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">l</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">m</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">n</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">o</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">p</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">q</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">r</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="">By Uploader</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="list"><a class="link" href="">E</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Any idea how to implement the css? When I hover the mouse over to the 'Browse' I want it to show the 2 dropdown list 'By Category' and 'By Uploader', then at the same time when the mouse is hovering on top of 'By Category', I want the sublist to appear. When the mouse is not hovering, I want the the dropdown/sublist to disappear.

An additional, when I'm on this page, I would like the list 'A' to be darker background than the others (current link).

Sorry for asking a newb question, as I'm quite new to building a website :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned before (`position:relative` and `position: absolute`), i've created a css example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhjbZ/)

```
a { color: gray; }
#navbar2 li:first-child a { color: black } /* make the letter A black */
#navbar2 li li:first-child a { color: gray } /* all others gray */

#navbar2 {}

/* Level 1 */
#navbar2 ul { padding: 5px;}
#navbar2 li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative; /* set the li-elements to relative, so the child-elements will be positioned on the parent element */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Level 2 */
#navbar2 ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0
}
#navbar2 li:hover ul { display: inline } /* show the second-level nav.. */
#navbar2 li:hover ul ul { display: none } /* but hide the 3rd */
#navbar2 li li {
    /* show the list, line after line */
    float:left;
    clear: left;
}

/* Level 3 */
#navbar2 ul ul ul {
    display: none; /* hide by default */
    width: 100px;
    background: #eee;
}
#navbar2 li li:hover ul {
    display: inline;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

jQuery is a good option, to get it work in IE6, where :hover doesn't work for elements except for the a-tag.

Comment: Thanks! It work.

Quick question though, How do I change the color if I select 'B', and the rest will become lighter than the 'B'?

btw, what's the point of having #navbar2 {}? I don't see any use of it.

Comment: You're welcome. You can delete the 2nd and 3rd selector and replace it with `li.active a, li:hover a {}` for example. Then your able to create active navigation points. Currently `#navbar2 {}` is just a placeholder, depending on your future design, it can be useful to have it already declared in your CSS (useful for firebug) ;)

Comment: Example: `#navbar2 li:hover a, #navbar2 li.active a { color: black } #navbar2 li:hover li a, #navbar2 li.active li a { color: gray }`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this with CSS but use jquery hover option instead.  You will need to set your navbar to position: relative and the dropdown menus will need to be absolute.  So on your sub ul's i would add a class to them.  You will need to style the by category ul to make sure it lines up correctly under the main navigation.

Next I would use jQuery hover to show/hide the by-category ul when you hover.  So this will require a unique id or class on the "Browse" or the li wrapping that link.

```
#navbar2 { position: relative; }
#by-category { position: absolute; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have made-

```
<style>
#navbar2 li{ border-radius:5px;list-style-type:none; list-style-position:inside; border:1px solid #bbb; padding:5; background:#383838; width:50}

#navbar2 .list:first-child{background:#fc7;} 

#navbar2 .list:first-child a{color:#383838}

#navbar2 a,#navbar2 a:visited{ text-decoration:none; color:#fc7}

#navbar2 .list{ float:left; }

#navbar2 a:hover{ color:blue }

#navbar2 li ul{ height:0; width:0; }

#navbar2 ul li ul li{ position:relative; top:5; width:100; left:-46; }

#navbar2 ul li ul{ display:none }

#navbar2 ul li ul li:first-child ul li{ left:65; top:-24; width:50; display:none}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#navbar2 ul li:eq(4)").mouseenter(function(){ 
    $("#navbar2 ul li ul").fadeIn(600);
  });
  $("#navbar2 ul li:eq(4)").mouseleave(function(){ 
    $("#navbar2 ul li ul").fadeOut(600); 
  }); 
  $("#navbar2 ul li ul li:first").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#navbar2 ul li ul li:first-child ul li").fadeIn(600); 
  });
  $("#navbar2 ul li ul li:first").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#navbar2 ul li ul li:first-child ul li").fadeOut(600);
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Now put it on your webpage. You may edit some  of the css according to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the code! There was a problem with the JS though, It kept blinking when I hover on the second sublist. The layout also altered when I hovered on top of it.