# Hover over span to show drop down list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a drop down list when mouse hovers over a text.. Currently my html is as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <span style="font-size:26px">nature : <strong class="link">DROPDOWN</strong>
        <ul class="dlist">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
```

Currently my CSS looks like this:

```
.link:hover{
      color:green;
 }
```

I'm kind of stuck on what step to take after this to show the dropdown list.

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaScript solution? CSS only? There are a lot of paths you can take...

Comment: <SPAN> is inline element and <UL> is block element. You should not nest a block element in an inline element. It won't solve your problem, but it's a thing to keep in mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigation Bar with on hover drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870879/navigation-bar-with-on-hover-drop-down)

Comment: I'd like a javascript solution since I'm not trying to mess with my css. I'm not too experienced with css.

Comment: Please post your JS, so that we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

**CSS**

```
.dlist {
    display: none;
}
.link:hover + .dlist {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the `<ul>` is a child of the `<span>`, not its sibling.

Comment: @flowstoneknight That doesn't matter – it is the strong that is hovered here (`.link`) not the `span`…

Answer (score 1):

You can try it using jquery.
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4b98Lbez/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span').click(function(){
        $('.dlist').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `hover` with jquery and change `ul` to `select` element:
HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <span class="myspan" style="font-size:26px">nature : <strong class="link">DROPDOWN</strong>
        <br/>
        <select id="mydrlist" style="display:none">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.myspan').hover(function() {
    $("#mydrlist").show();
}, function() {
    $("#mydrlist").hide();
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q2shzbfc/):